# How to make the snake continue in that direction until another arrow key is pressed

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

I've tried many ideas like importing pynput but it kept on crashing and making my computer messed up. I've tried putting it in a loop but that didn't work as well and kept crashing

```
import sys
import pygame
import random
import os
import time

pygame.init()

#assigns thingys to window adjustments
size = width, height = 750, 750
white = 255, 255, 255
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")

#The coordinates and size of the snake square thingy
x = 350
y = 350
w  = 25
h = 25
ax = range(30,700)
ay = range(40,700)
aw = 15 
ah = 15
vel = 10
vertical1 = 9000
vertical2 = 0 

score_value = 0 
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
textx = 10
testy = 10

def show_score(x, y): 
    score = font.render("Score: "+ str(score_value), True, (255,0,0))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))


def divisible_random(a,b,n):
    if b-a < n:
      raise Exception('{} is too big'.format(n))
    result = random.randint(a, b)
    while result % n != 0:
      result = random.randint(a, b)
    return result

def apple(x,y):
   pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0),  (arx, ary, aw, ah))



arx = divisible_random(30,700,10)
ary = divisible_random(40,700,10)



    

while 1:
    
    #Delays the movement so you can see snake thingy fps
    pygame.time.delay(25)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    #gets the presses to move the snake 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        while True:
            x= x - vel
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                break

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        while True:
            x= x + vel
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                break


    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        while True:
            y = y + vel
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                break

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        while True:
            y = y - vel
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                break

    screen.fill(white)

    #The snake thingy and apple thingy
    apple(arx, ary)
    snake = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y, w, h))
    diffrencex = abs(arx-x)
    diffrencey = abs(ary-y)

    if ((x == arx and y == ary) or ((diffrencex == 10 and x < arx) and (diffrencey == 10 and y < ary)) or ((diffrencex==10 and x< arx) and (y == ary)) or ((x == arx) and (diffrencey==10 and y< ary))):
        score_value += 1
        arx = divisible_random(30,700,10)
        ary = divisible_random(40,700,10)

    #Borders for the frame thingy 
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (14, 10), (14, 800), 30)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (734, 10), (734, 800), 30) 
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (9000, 734), (0 , 734), 30) 
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (9000, 24), (0 , 24), 30) 
  
    if x < 30:
        x = 700
    
    if x > 700:
        x = 30
    
    if y > 700:
        y = 40
    
    if y < 40:
        y = 700

    show_score(textx, testy)
    

    print(arx,ary,x,y)

    pygame.display.update()  
pygame.quit
```

I know the code isn't neat not organized but I'm working on it as soon as I finish making the game

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        while True:
            x= x - vel
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                break

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        while True:
            x= x + vel
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                break


    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        while True:
            y = y + vel
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                break

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        while True:
            y = y - vel
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                break
```

I encounter problems here to be exact

Comment: Get rid of all those while True loops to process keys.  You just want to process the pressed key once, and set a direction variable based on the key.  right now, as soon as  a key is pressed, you run a very fast increment loop with no screen updates or anything.  A crash is sure to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Use the keyboard events (`KEYDOWN`, `KEYUP` - see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)) rather than [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed). Add a variable `direction` and change the state tof the variable when <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd> respectively <kbd>DOWN</kbd> is pressed. Change the player's position according to the direction:

```py
direction = (0, 0)

while 1:
    
    #Delays the movement so you can see snake thingy fps
    pygame.time.delay(25)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = (-1, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                direction = (1, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                direction = (0, -1)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                direction = (0, 1)

    x += vel * direction[0]
    y += vel * direction[1]
```

You want continuous movement, but you don't want to hold down the button. You want to move the snake even if no key is pressed. Therefore, you need to save the direction of movement in a variable and change the direction **once** when a key is pressed. The keyboard event occurs **once** when a key is pressed and is the right choice to change direction.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to store the direction of movement. Have key presses affect that variable. Then, check that variable every loop iteration, and move the snake according to the direction.